# Cannot receive data from stream

Tags: toit

I'm acting according to the recommendation because this error regularly appears when running *toit* at the very end of the app execution over the past few days on April 22, 23 as a free addition. But the app is performed normally, judging by the log:

```
Cannot receive data from stream: rpc error: code = Internal desc = stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: INTERNAL_ERROR
Internal error.
If the issue persists please report it to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our API has a timeout on all requests. All long running requests  will be cancelled and this error often comes as the result of it.

If you want to run code on a device for a long period of time you should use 'toit deploy.

Atm. I can't remember the exact timeout but it is in the span 120-300sec.